# Errors -19 and 13 Android Studio

Tags: android

I was trying to perform an insert into my local DB in my app. If I leave empty my three editText (that I want to insert) I get these:

```
E/MP-Decision: Error 13 setting online status to 0 for cpu1
E/MP-Decision: Error(-19) changing core 1 status to offline
```

and these errors doesn't stop to appear.
I want to insert two strings and a float number, so I use this control to avoid that situation, but it doesn't work:

```
if((!description.isEmpty())&&(!title.isEmpty())&&(!amount.isNaN())){}
```

The query on the DB works fine if title,amount ad description aren't empty. What kind of errors are they?

Comment: On first look, the errors don't seem related to your app at all.

Comment: Perfect, because I don't do anything complicated in that part of code. So I don't have to worry about them?